# Possible types of elements for generic collections

Tags: java, generics, collections

```
List<? super MyClass> parentsOfMyclass
List<? extends MyClass> childsOfMyclassFirst
List<T extends MyClass> childsOfMyclassSecond
```

Please explain me what types valid to add in these collections ? I can add instance of `MyClass` to all of these collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<? super MyClass>` - contains something that is superclass of `MyClass`, which means that you can put only `MyClass` and it superclasses here.

`List<? extends MyClass>` - contains something that extends `MyClass`, which means that you can't add anything here (because you don't know which subclass is used **exactly**). Although you can say for sure, that items are `MyClass` (or subclasses).

`List<T extends MyClass>` - contains `T`, that is subclass of `MyClass`. Can only add `T` and subclasses of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually use the last option like that. It can be used in class declaration, but not in variable declaration.

```
static class MyClass {}

static class My2ndClass extends MyClass {}

static class ListExt<T extends MyClass> {}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<? super MyClass> parentsOfMyclass;
    List<? extends MyClass> childsOfMyclassFirst;
    List<T extends MyClass> childsOfMyclassSecond; //error

    ListExt<? extends MyClass> extList;


    childsOfMyclassFirst.add(new MyClass()); //error 
    parentsOfMyclass.add(new MyClass());
    extList.add(new MyClass()); // error
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add instance of MyClass only in the first case (with super). `? super MyClass` makes the list a consumer, it can namely receive objects of type MyClass. In the second case the list cannot receive anything, it is a producer, a read-only list. In the third case you can add a subtype of MyClass if you make downcasting before: `.add((T)object);` and it of couse it does not throw an exception.

The correct syntax of the third case would be `List<T> list` and `T extends MyClass` should be in the class declaration.